# How can I see the edit history?

Tags: support, comments, edits, answers

Suppose someone has commented or answered my question. Is it possible to check the edit history of comments and answers to find out what was changed?

Comment: Comments: no. Answers: yes, by clicking the "edited..." link

Comment: This is already answered in the linked faq, under "How can you tell what has been changed between edits?"

Answer (score 1):

There's no UI for comment edit history (although we do track it). It was never built because comments can only be edited for 5 minutes after they're posted and the vast majority of them are never altered.

For answers (or questions, for that matter), you can click on the "edited on {time}" timestamp to view the revision history:

> [image]

Comment: Well I think stack exchange should add this feature. If a user submit a question/answer or comment  and people comment or answer him, what if he/she(asker) edit and changes the bad part of his comment/question/answer, people who answer them or find and point the bad part (e.g. a syntax error in code) are proved wrong.